# sailsjs beforeCreate is not triggered

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js

I have a blank sails 0.9.8 app with a very basic model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    nickname: 'string',
    encryptedPassword: 'string',

    beforeCreate: function(values, next){
        values.encryptedPassword = "123";
        next();
    }   
  }

};
```

When I create a new User from the console, the beforeCreate method is not called, thus no encryptedPassword created.
I'm sure I'm missing a little something here but cannot find out what. Any idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to place beforeCreate outside of the attributes. See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/models.md#lifecycle-callbacks