# beforeCreate not triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to use this model (User.js) with my SailsJs app :

```
module.export = {
    attributes: {
        //Some attributes
    },

    beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
        if (!values.password || values.password != values.confirmation) {
            var err = {
                err: ['Password does not match password confirmation']
            };
            return (next(err));
        }
        require('bcrypt').hash(values.password, 10, function passwordEncrypted(err, encryptedPassword) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            values.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
            next();
        });
    }
};
```

But beforeCreate does not seems to be triggered when I create a user. What could be the reason?
I tried to use it with some console.log() calls in it but nothing appears.
I succeed to use user/create on the other hand.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to create a user?  Also, it should be plural - `module.exports = `, which might be causing an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sailsjs beforeCreate is not triggered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093104/sailsjs-beforecreate-is-not-triggered)

Comment: @JohnDeerhake It seems like it was that. I just changed that and it worked. :) Thank you!